# modify installed Office 2007 - remove Access

Tags: ms-access, installation, silent

I want to modify the existing installation of Office 2007 on the computer.
I want to use `setup.exe /modify config.xml`

But I don't know what to put into `config.xml` to make it work.

Please help

Comment: [Office 2007 customized install walkthrough](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/odsupport/2009/06/10/office-2007-customized-install-walkthrough/) should help.

Comment: Yes, Also this helped a lot:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/odsupport/2009/06/10/customize-office-2007-by-using-the-config-xml/

Answer (score -1):

[AddAccess.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cglzG.png)

and then running setup.exe /config RemoveAccess.xml working.

Comment: Don't show code as image, just use text ([formated as code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)) to  simplify reading and copying